# How can my CodeBuild in a CodePipeline resolve resources created by the previous CloudFormation step?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have setup my CodePipeline something like:

1. Source: Github
2. CodeBuild: Package SAM application (CloudFormation resources like DB)
3. Deploy CloudFormation: Does the create & execute changesets
4. CodeBuild: I want to run DB migrations for the DB created by CloudFormation ... but how do I get it ... CodeBuild does not support parameters from my Pipeline

Maybe I am creating my pipeline wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CloudFormation action can output stack parameters, but currently the CodeBuild action in CodePipeline can't accept both a code artifact and an artifact with CloudFormation outputs.

For now I'd call [aws cloudformation describe-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) from the CLI inside your build script to retrieve the DB information from your CloudFormation stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the step 3. You setup your cloudformation in this way:

1- create the database...Export as an output the name of the database

```
Outputs:
    DataBaseName:
        Description: "Name of the Database"
        Value: !Ref DataBaseName
```

2- In the codebuild use the Boto3 and use the [Describe Stacks](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.describe_stacks) and get the output (the name of the database and another information about it), now you could take advangate of Python in your codebuild and start the migration usign Boto3.

```
response = client.describe_stacks(
    StackName='string',
    NextToken='string'
)
```